# phpStorm CodeIgniter enable autocomplete

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete, phpstorm

Google didn't help me, because previous decides don't work with phpStorm 7.1.3 and CI 2.1.3. At least my own modules don't show. This comment:

```
/**
 * @property my_module $my_module
 */
```

doesn't work.

I mean that phpStorm doesn't know about my modules and doesn't show list with modules.

For example, I'm typing:

$this->my_module->.......

and this constuction doesn't know anything about my modules.

ok, I declare new module:

```
/**
 * @property my_module $my_module description of my module
 */

class my_module extends CI_Module {

// Some methods...

}
```

and in controller I can't see autocompletion for $my_module. 
For example: I type in controller: $this->my_module->  ... and nothing ...

PS Sorry for bad english =)

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" about your comment? In general, the more information you can give us about your problem, the better we can help you.

Comment: Please show whole file -- I want to see where did you put such PHPDoc comment etc